# Flag "print" statements in Python code

Tags: python, lint, static-code-analysis

I don't want "print" statements in our Python modules, because we will be using a logger.

I'm trying to generate a script to check modules with pylint.
However, pylint currently does not detect this as a warning or error.

I want to detect "print" invocations as an error or a warning in accordance with our internal Python programming standard.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`flake8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8) has a [`flake8-print`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8-print) plugin specifically for the task:

> flake8-print
>
> Check for Print statements in python files.

DEMO:

```
$ cat test.py
s = "test"
print s

$ flake8 test.py
test.py:2:1: T001 print statement found.
```

Comment: Shameless plug, but flake8-print has some dependencies that made it unusable in one of projects I was working on. I found this thread though and created my own package that detects print statements: [NoPrint](https://pypi.org/project/noprint/). No dependencies outside of what's already included with basic Python installation. Should be working on Linux, Mac and Windows with Py >= 3.7.

Answer (score 10):

If for some reason you don't want to use `flake8-print` as suggested by @alecxe you can roll your own using the `ast` module - which makes use of Python's compiler to parse the file so you can reliably find `print` (instead of lines just starting with `print`):

**Code**:

```
import ast

with open('blah.py') as fin:
    parsed = ast.parse(fin.read())

for node in ast.walk(parsed):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Print):
        print 'print at line {} col {}'.format(node.lineno, node.col_offset)
```

**blah.py**:

```
def print_test():
    print 'hello'

print 'goodbye'
```

**Output**:

```
print at line 4 col 0
print at line 2 col 1
```

You can use `os.walk` or `os.listdir` or whatever's most suitable if you wish to navigate a folder or subfolder.

Comment: Nice alternative! FYI, [`flake8-print`](https://github.com/JBKahn/flake8-print/blob/master/flake8_print.py) uses regex-approach.

Comment: My 20 cents I make for detects a "import pdb" setence too: https://gist.github.com/moylop260/10f3e5c7e1c3acfa0ffb

Comment: Cool, I wrote flake8-print mostly because we needed something at work. I didn't know about ast. I'm going to take a look at this when I have time.

Comment: @JosephKahn, the problem with regex in flake8-print is with setence print but not print. Example: "comment with word print bad for flake8-print". Can you give me your repository and I can make a PR

Comment: @JosephKahn, Oh cool, I saw this commit change: https://github.com/JBKahn/flake8-print/commit/a0c09442f8d7945eb2afe2bba8fa567434a2f143

Comment: @moylop260 Ya, I'll take a look at making a non-regex change to flake8-debugger as well, just got pretty busy with classes.

Comment: FYI now pylint add support to detect print sentence with enable E1601

Comment: @moylop260 the question is about disabling `print` in favour to logging for example. E1601 is about disabling `print` statements in favour to `print` function. It doesn't warn when you use `print` function.

Comment: Checking for `isinstance(node, ast.Print)` won't work with newer versions. For Python 3 use `node.__dict__.get("id") == "print"` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Ruff](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff), which implements the same [flake8-print rules](https://beta.ruff.rs/docs/rules/#flake8-print-t20).

Using this simple one line file.

```py
print("Hello print!")
```

Can be quickly checked for print statements with ruff by selecting the T rules.

```
(venv) PS G:\Testing> ruff test.py --select T
test.py:1:1: T201 `print` found
Found 1 error.
```

For a more permanent way to enable the rules, you can [check the different to configure ruff](https://beta.ruff.rs/docs/configuration/).

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect: lines like 'print_something()' would be detected, too. But most cases should be catched with this:

```
import os
import sys

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    dirs.sort()
    for file in files:
        file=os.path.join(root, file)
        for i, line in enumerate(open(file)):
            line=line.strip()
            if line.startswith('print'):
                print file, i, line
```

Comment: FYI now pylint support print sentence with error: E1601