# How to detect top-level print() and logging calls that execute on Python module import?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, pytest

I'd like to detect calls to `print()` and `logging` (e.g. `logging.info()`) that are top-level reachable, i.e. that execute on module load, and fail the build if found.

I maintain a service that other teams often frequently commit to, so I want this as a lint-check of sorts in CI. How can I do this?

I don't care about non-top-level calls (e.g. calls inside a function). I'd like to continue allowing these other teams to do so if they really want, for when they exec their own code.

I've tried/encountered several things without success thus far, generally dynamic `import_module` of all python files I care about and then:

- `pytest`'s `capsys`/`capfd` feature, maybe due to bug? https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5997#issuecomment-1028710193
  For example:

```py
# foo.py
print("hello")
```

```py
from importlib import import_module

def test_does_not_print(capfd):
    import_module('foo')
    out, err = capfd.readouterr()

    assert out == ""  # surprise: this will pass
```

- walk the `ast`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25249854/234593 (difficult to tell if top-level reachable)
- [Mock Python's built in print function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998908/mock-pythons-built-in-print-function)

Comment: `capfd` will capture the output in your example, just as `capsys` will as well, so it's not an issue with `pytest`. I rather assume that you have already imported `foo` before actually executing the test, so `import_module` will just take the cached module from `sys.modules`. If you clean up `sys.modules` before calling `import_module` (e.g. `sys.modules.pop('foo', None)`), or use `importlib.reload(foo)`, the import mechanism will be triggered anew and the output will be actually printed and captured.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What I pasted/linked really is a complete and minimal repro, i.e. my code doesn't import `foo` elsewhere. A `sys.modules['foo']` before `import_module` even `KeyError`s. However, adding `sys.modules.pop('foo', None)` does indeed make it fail for `""`, as expected. This unexpected behavior smells of a `pytest` bug to me.

Comment: The repro works for me: https://replit.com/@hoefling/CrimsonThunderousElectricity?v=1

Comment: Thanks for checking. Just tried in a different project/venv I have, and also getting expected behavior. Must be some strange interaction bug in this project -- pytest plugin or else. Unfortunately not sure I'll have the time dive even deeper into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** The below is a workaround, as `capsys`/`capfd` should be able to solve this problem, but doesn't work for my particular project for an unknown reason.

I've been able to accomplish this via runtime monkeypatching the `print` and `logging.info` functions in an independent script that I can run during CI, e.g.:

```py
import builtins
from contextlib import contextmanager
import functools as ft
from importlib import import_module
import logging
import os
import sys

orig_print = builtins.print
orig_info, orig_warning, orig_error, orig_critical = logging.info, logging.warning, logging.error, logging.critical
NO_ARG = object()
sys.path.insert(0, 'src')


def main():
    orig_print("Checking files for print() & logging on import...")
    for path in files_under_watch():
        orig_print("  " + path)
        output = detect_toplevel_output(path)
        if output:
            raise SyntaxWarning(f"Top-level output (print & logging) detected in {path}: {output}")


def files_under_watch():
    for root, _, files in os.walk('src'):
        for file in files:
            if should_watch_file(file):  # your impl here
                yield os.path.join(root, file)


def detect_toplevel_output(python_file_path):
    with capture_print() as printed, capture_logging() as logged:
        module_name = python_file_path[:-3].replace('/', '.')
        import_module(module_name)

    output = {'print': printed, 'logging': logged}
    return {k: v for k, v in output.items() if v}


@contextmanager
def capture_print():
    calls = []

    @ft.wraps(orig_print)
    def captured_print(*args, **kwargs):
        calls.append((args, kwargs))
        return orig_print(*args, **kwargs)

    builtins.print = captured_print
    yield calls
    builtins.print = orig_print


@contextmanager
def capture_logging():
    calls = []

    @ft.wraps(orig_info)
    def captured_info(*args, **kwargs):
        calls.append(('info', args, kwargs))
        return orig_info(*args, **kwargs)

    @ft.wraps(orig_warning)
    def captured_warning(*args, **kwargs):
        calls.append(('warning', args, kwargs))
        return orig_warning(*args, **kwargs)

    @ft.wraps(orig_error)
    def captured_error(*args, **kwargs):
        calls.append(('error', args, kwargs))
        return orig_error(*args, **kwargs)

    @ft.wraps(orig_critical)
    def captured_critical(*args, **kwargs):
        calls.append(('critical', args, kwargs))
        return orig_critical(*args, **kwargs)

    logging.info, logging.warning, logging.error, logging.critical = captured_info, captured_warning, captured_error, captured_critical
    yield calls
    logging.info, logging.warning, logging.error, logging.critical = orig_info, orig_warning, orig_error, orig_critical


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```